# Help with tracking data usage by connection/network (SSID) rather than interface (MAC)

Tags: bash, scripts, .desktop, traffic

I need to be able to track the traffic of my wireless interface by *"network"*.

I move around a lot. Some of the places I work **have usage limits**, other do not. I always connect via the same interface.

**What I have already done:**

- installed `vnstat`
- configured `vnstat` to track my wireless interface

**What I am thinking I might be able to do:**

Write a bash script that runs each time I connect to a wireless network to reconfigure vnstat to switch (or create) to a unique DB for that network.

**The Issue:**

I have no real experience writing Bash scripts, and not enough experience to determine if this is in fact possible, or if there is a better solution.

I'm hoping for some general guidance / advice (but wouldn't say no to a working solution).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think Wireshark can do this: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/49177/can-i-see-all-traffic-on-wifi

Comment: It might be able to do what I need, I'll check it out.